# C# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:Index was out of range

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2003

I need some help, I'm kinda new to this problem..

```
DataGridViewCell cell = null;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell selectedCell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            cell = selectedCell;
            break;
        }
        if (cell != null)
        {

            DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
            idgene.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            first.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            last.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            mid.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            address.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            yeaar = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();



        }
```

This is the first time I encountered this kind of problem, Every time I add the combobox.text this gives me this error,System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:Index was out of range,Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I also tried this this but it didn't solved my problem:

```
if (cell != null)
        {
            string yeaar = "";
            syear.Text = yeaar;
            DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
            idgene.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            first.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            last.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            mid.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            address.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            yeaar = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();



        }
```

Comment: When you debug this, which line throws the exception?  There's a good chance that the `Cells` collection doesn't have 6 elements, which the code assumes that it does.

Comment: Sir @David, oh! snap I forgot that my datagrid only has a 4 cells which is "SELECT  ID,Firstname,Lastname,Middlename,course FROM studentinfo". I was scratching my head for hours trying to point where the problem is, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your if statement to

(this is using System.Linq)

if (cell != null && cell.OwningRow.Cells.Count() >= 6)

and if you don't have enough cells it won't execute so you will have to account for that

Comment: thanks sir, I solved it! I really don't have enough cells because my query is = "SELECT ID,Firstname,Lastname,Middlename,course FROM studentinfo", Well, I'm really sleepy to see that mistake.